# What can be the cause of sudden lag spikes in my Android game?

Tags: android, java, opengl-es, game-loop

My Android game has sudden lag spikes sometimes. I know this is due to something going wrong. My phone has a 1GHz processor so there shouldn't be a problem. Basically I use the `Canvas` class to render my entire game (I am about to learn OpenGL and don't know if this is the cause). I have a main game loop and about 4 threads. Why does it lag?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, thats what I meant. "Lag: Fall behind in movement, progress, or development; not keep pace with another or others." And why do i have such a lousy frame rate?

Comment: Could be canvas, but wait for someone who knows the Android platform better, to answer your question. GL. Also -- you may want to post your code.

Comment: How do you know it's "due to something going wrong"? Perhaps your phone is doing other things that are slowing down your application like checking for updates or emails.

Comment: -1, way too little detail here to give a reasonable answer.

Comment: GC potentially? They are usually really bad on mobile platforms; what how many objects you are creating - pool/re-use objects if necessary; I know this is a problem with C# on XBox+WP7 (which both have an inferior GC) - so this may very well apply to Java too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is most presumably the garbage collector kicking in.

There is no clean way to solve this problem unless you are willing to ditch Java for another language such as C++. See [How can I avoid garbage collection delays in Java games? (Best Practices)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2484079/111461) for a few hints on how to mitigate the problem.

Comment: Yes there is, object pooling, as long as you're not using dynamic memory allocation in the game loop you can work around it.

Comment: I don't think manually managing memory in c++ is a more clean way of solving this problem than.. manually managing the memory in Java , using object pools or plain hunting allocations down, moving them out loops, etc.

Comment: @Tinco: well I think going to C++ has many other advantages including portability.

Comment: Im gonna switch to OpenGL ES