# Too many if statements cause lag?

Tags: android, libgdx, lag

I am trying to make a vertical scroller game with collision tiles on both sides. I'm using Libgdx and android studio.

The problem is that i have made every tile as an object with a rectangle for collision and there are 12 on each side that get checked every time the update method is called. I noticed the game hangs sometimes, can this this cause the lag?

My code for collision:

```
    public boolean collidesOuterCircle(Penguin penguin) {

    if(penguin.getX()>(136/2)){
        return (

            dirtRight1.collidesOuterCircle(penguin)|| dirtRight2.collidesOuterCircle(penguin)||dirtRight3.collidesOuterCircle(penguin)
                    ||dirtRight4.collidesOuterCircle(penguin)||
            dirtRight5.collidesOuterCircle(penguin)||dirtRight6.collidesOuterCircle(penguin)||dirtRight7.collidesOuterCircle(penguin)
                    ||dirtRight8.collidesOuterCircle(penguin)||dirtRight9.collidesOuterCircle(penguin)
            ||dirtRight10.collidesOuterCircle(penguin)||
            dirtRight11.collidesOuterCircle(penguin)||dirtRight12.collidesOuterCircle(penguin));

    }
    else {
        return( dirtLeft1.collidesOuterCircle(penguin)|| dirtLeft2.collidesOuterCircle(penguin)||dirtLeft3.collidesOuterCircle(penguin)||
                dirtLeft4.collidesOuterCircle(penguin)||
                dirtLeft5.collidesOuterCircle(penguin)||dirtLeft6.collidesOuterCircle(penguin)||
                dirtLeft7.collidesOuterCircle(penguin)||dirtLeft8.collidesOuterCircle(penguin)||
                dirtLeft9.collidesOuterCircle(penguin)||
                dirtLeft10.collidesOuterCircle(penguin)||dirtLeft11.collidesOuterCircle(penguin)||dirtLeft12.collidesOuterCircle(penguin));

    }


}

    public boolean collidesInnerCircle(Penguin penguin) {

    if(penguin.getX()>(136/2)){
        return(
        dirtRight1.collidesInnerCircle(penguin)|| dirtRight2.collidesInnerCircle(penguin)||dirtRight3.collidesInnerCircle(penguin)||dirtRight4.collidesInnerCircle(penguin)||
                dirtRight5.collidesInnerCircle(penguin)||dirtRight6.collidesInnerCircle(penguin)||dirtRight7.collidesInnerCircle(penguin)||dirtRight8.collidesInnerCircle(penguin)||dirtRight9.collidesInnerCircle(penguin)
                ||dirtRight10.collidesInnerCircle(penguin)||
                dirtRight11.collidesInnerCircle(penguin)||dirtRight12.collidesInnerCircle(penguin));
    }else{
    return (dirtLeft1.collidesInnerCircle(penguin)|| dirtLeft2.collidesInnerCircle(penguin)||dirtLeft3.collidesInnerCircle(penguin)||dirtLeft4.collidesInnerCircle(penguin)||
            dirtLeft5.collidesInnerCircle(penguin)||dirtLeft6.collidesInnerCircle(penguin)||dirtLeft7.collidesInnerCircle(penguin)||dirtLeft8.collidesInnerCircle(penguin)||dirtLeft9.collidesInnerCircle(penguin)||
            dirtLeft10.collidesInnerCircle(penguin)||dirtLeft11.collidesInnerCircle(penguin)||dirtLeft12.collidesInnerCircle(penguin));
    }



}
```

My code for reseting the tiles:

```
  if (dirtLeft1.isScrolledDown()) {
        dirtLeft1.reset(dirtLeft12.getTailY());
    } else if (dirtLeft2.isScrolledDown()) {
        dirtLeft2.reset(dirtLeft1.getTailY());
    } else if (dirtLeft3.isScrolledDown()) {
        dirtLeft3.reset(dirtLeft2.getTailY());
    }else if (dirtLeft4.isScrolledDown()) {
        dirtLeft4.reset(dirtLeft3.getTailY());
    }else if (dirtLeft5.isScrolledDown()) {
        dirtLeft5.reset(dirtLeft4.getTailY());
    }else if (dirtLeft6.isScrolledDown()) {
        dirtLeft6.reset(dirtLeft5.getTailY());
    }
      else if (dirtLeft7.isScrolledDown()) {
          dirtLeft7.reset(dirtLeft6.getTailY());
      }
      else if (dirtLeft8.isScrolledDown()) {
          dirtLeft8.reset(dirtLeft7.getTailY());
      }

      else if (dirtLeft9.isScrolledDown()) {
          dirtLeft9.reset(dirtLeft8.getTailY());
      }
      else if (dirtLeft10.isScrolledDown()) {
          dirtLeft10.reset(dirtLeft9.getTailY());
      }
      else if (dirtLeft11.isScrolledDown()) {
          dirtLeft11.reset(dirtLeft10.getTailY());
      }
      else if (dirtLeft12.isScrolledDown()) {
          dirtLeft12.reset(dirtLeft11.getTailY());
      }

    if (dirtRight1.isScrolledDown()) {
        dirtRight1.reset(dirtRight12.getTailY());
    } else if (dirtRight2.isScrolledDown()) {
        dirtRight2.reset(dirtRight1.getTailY());
    } else if (dirtRight3.isScrolledDown()) {
        dirtRight3.reset(dirtRight2.getTailY());
    }else if (dirtRight4.isScrolledDown()) {
        dirtRight4.reset(dirtRight3.getTailY());
    }else if (dirtRight5.isScrolledDown()) {
        dirtRight5.reset(dirtRight4.getTailY());
    }else if (dirtRight6.isScrolledDown()) {
        dirtRight6.reset(dirtRight5.getTailY());
    }
    else if (dirtRight7.isScrolledDown()) {
        dirtRight7.reset(dirtRight6.getTailY());
    }else if (dirtRight8.isScrolledDown()) {
        dirtRight8.reset(dirtRight7.getTailY());
    }else if (dirtRight9.isScrolledDown()) {
        dirtRight9.reset(dirtRight8.getTailY());
    }else if (dirtRight10.isScrolledDown()) {
        dirtRight10.reset(dirtRight9.getTailY());
    }else if (dirtRight11.isScrolledDown()) {
        dirtRight11.reset(dirtRight10.getTailY());
    }else if (dirtRight12.isScrolledDown()) {
        dirtRight12.reset(dirtRight11.getTailY());
    }
```

Comment: First of all try to write some more general collision checking. You seem to be saving your level objects as on variable each. Try to use arrays or other collection types. Then use for-loops (foreach perhaps) to do the collision checking. Secondly: We can't answer this question without having access to your whole code, which is, by all means, not appropiate on Stack Exchange. If you have perfomance issues profile your code and find out in which part of your code the most time is spent. Then improve that part.

Comment: It very likely hangs because of... android. The Java VM was likely running GC whenever you experienced lags. This is well-known problem with many web resources covering it. Checking n^2 (=144) collisions can hardly have any impact on performance even with not-optimized code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can be the cause of sudden lag spikes in my Android game?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19902/what-can-be-the-cause-of-sudden-lag-spikes-in-my-android-game)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I save each tile as a dirt object like this private DirtRight dirtRight1,dirtRight2... Will a for loop peform better than many ifs`? Won't it just be the same since you loop troughe them all and check for collison every time with a if? Also how do you profil your code in android studio? Nerver used it before.

Comment: @Morti for(each) does not yield a perfomance boost, as -like you already noted- the same operations are performed. However it makes your code **much more** readable and **way** easier to extend. To profile your code use stopwatches (Java should provide some built in types for this, google it) and just measure the time spent in the individual code parts. Output them to a file (or just look at them via the debugger).

Answer (score 2):

*Cursory answer*: "it might be". If you are doing "carpet testing" for collision detection, no offence, but you are doing it wrong (unless you have *very few* elements to test): pair checking of any kind is a O(n^2) operation, and will start to eat at your cpu time very fast as the number of objects you have in the game increases, so you *might* want to improve your algorithm (there are many). **However...**

...since the tiles don't collide with each othets, your tests are likely far less than most modern devices can handle (even low tier phones), so I wouldn't put my money on that :)

The point is, **why guess**? *The right thing to do* (instead of making people read tons of code ;-) ) is to pick the android "monitor", profile your game cycle and see where the bottleneck really is. See how much time your inner and outer collision detection functions are taking (exclusive time) and you'll have your answer, without margin of error.

Still, If I had to put my money somewhere, I would bet that the profiler will not point you to those two functions, as the culprits of your performance issue, as the symptoms you are describing (game that runs smoothly and then hangs for a while) look a textbook case of *memory allocation* problem.

I have not enough data, but might it be that you are creating objects in you tight loop? In that case, you might be allocating memory faster than the garbage collector is recycling it. This leads the Os to exhaust the memory for the process at set (**very periodic**, in fact) times, and hang the process while the garbage collector "catches up".

In conclusion: give a good look at the profiler (just to see that it exists, if you never used one already ;-) ), but then check the memory and CPU consumption graphs at the bottom of Android Studio (which are a very quick way to get pointed in the right direction with performance related problems): if the average CPU consumption is not high, but you see a sawtooth shape in the memory consumption, then you should definitely check your allocations (-> profile them with the monitor ;-) ) and make sure not to do any in your tights loops.

Hope it helps 
(and break a leg for your game!)

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort to help me ! I will definitely look into what you have written :)

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to mark the answer as the correct one, if it solves your question (of course, if a better ones doesn't appear). Cheers!